# Error AsyncStorage : Passing null/undefined as value is not supported

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to save my object "user" with AsyncStorage. But when I try to save it with "AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));", I get the error : Passing null/undefined as value is not supported. I have used expo to create the app.

Here is my code :

const onLoginPress = async () => {
setLoading(true);

```
axios.post('http://romain.eamuscork.local/api/user/UsersLogin', {
  email: email,
  password: password
})
.then(response => {
  const user = response.data.result;
  if (user) {
    console.log('Utilisateur connecté :', user.name);
    console.log('User :', user);
    if(user){
      AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    setLoading(false);
    props.onLoginSuccess();
  } else {
    setError('Mauvais identifiant ou mot de passe');
    setLoading(false);
  }
})
.catch(error => {
    if (error.response) {
        // erreur de réponse
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.headers);
        setError('Mauvais identifiant ou mot de passe.');
        setLoading(false);
    } else if (error.request) {
        // erreur de réseau
        console.log(error.request);
        setError('Une erreur s\'est produite. [Erreur réseau]');
        setLoading(false);
    } else {
        // autre erreur
        console.log('Error', error.message);
        setError('Une erreur s\'est produite. Veuillez réessayer plus tard.');
        setLoading(false);
    }
});
```

}

Here are the logs :

```
User : {"connexionv1": "", "created_at": "2023-01-13T15:49:33.000000Z", "current_team_id": null, "email": "**********", "email_verified_at": "2023-01-13T15:49:33.000000Z", "id": 48, "name": " Romain ******", "profile_photo_path": null, "profile_photo_url": "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=+Romain+******&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF", "status": 1, "updated_at": "2023-04-13T07:57:55.000000Z"}
 LOG  [Error: [AsyncStorage] Passing null/undefined as value is not supported. If you want to remove value, Use .removeItem method instead.
Passed value: undefined
Passed key: user
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, you could try logging JSON.stringify(user) and see what the result is, maybe something goes wrong there and returns null.

Comment: I already tried it, the result is good...

Comment: Ok, my bad, i didn't pass user in "onLoginSuccess", works better now. Sorry.